# LibGDX issue setting black screen and showing white text

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, windows-10

I'm having an issue with LibGDX.

I followed their guide on GitHub and then i went ahead modifying the game. (Ref: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game)

I wanted to create a game over screen when the drop touched the ground 3 times.
When it touches the ground for the 3rd time, i set lost to true, and at the start of the render() method i check if lost is true.

This is the contenent:

```
        if(lost){
        bucket.dispose();
        lostSound.play();
        sprite.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        drop.dispose();
        font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        GlyphLayout layout = new GlyphLayout(font, "Game Over!");
        int fontX = 800 + 64 / 2;
        int fontY = 480 / 2;
        sprite.begin();
        font.draw(sprite, layout, fontX, fontY);
        sprite.end();
        return;
    }
```

The lostSound is sorta bugged, it repeats his start at the infinite, and i get a black screen without any Game Over text.

EDIT: If i run via command line i don't get any exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong every loop you are entering in `lost` condition, so the sound is playing every loop, add a flag like `gameover=true` for not entering again in the main loop. 
Also, which is your game resolution? If you want half of 864 (if is maximum resolution), center of X, you must do `fontX= (800+64)/2` (432) instead of `fontX= 800+64 /2` (832)

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried adding a boolean on when if(lost) is executed (and if it has been executed it returns) and now the screen flickers showing the Game Over screen and the game

Comment: That&#39;s because every loop is lost, your game don&#39;t stop when enters the `lost` condition, and not change `lost ` boolean to false. 
Try changing `if` to `while`